# Using beautiful soup in python attribute 'contents'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using the following code from the bool "Hello! Python":

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def get_stock_html(ticker_name):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),)
    opener.addhaders = [('User-agent', "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; " "Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; " ".NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)")]
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + ticker_name
    response = opener.open(url)
    return ''.join(response.readlines())

def find_quote_section(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    # quote = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'yfi_rt_quote_summary_rt_top'})
    quote = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'yfi_quote_summary'})
    return quote

def parse_stock_html(html, ticker_name):
    quote = find_quote_section(html)
    result = {}
    tick = ticker_name.lower()

    result['stock_name'] = quote.find('h2').contents[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.system("clear")
    html = get_stock_html('GOOG')
    # print find_quote_section(html)
    print parse_stock_html(html, 'GOOG')
```

getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dwlod.py", line 33, in <module>
    print parse_stock_html(html, 'GOOG')
  File "dwlod.py", line 25, in parse_stock_html
    result['stock_name'] = quote.find('h2').contents[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'
```

I'm a newbie and don't really know what to make of it.  Is the book just wrong?

**ADDED**

I just replaced `result['stock_name'] = quote.find('h2').contents[0]` with:

```
x = BeautifulSoup(html).find('h2').contents[0]
return x
```

Now, nothing gets returned, but the error no longer crops up.  So, is there something wrong with the original python syntax?

Comment: It's likely the API has changed between when the book was written and now

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thanks!  Where can I find the correct API?

Comment: Good question. I suggest you take a look at what that Yahoo page (the URL it queries) returns (I would but am on a mobile device). Are you familiar enough with BeautifulSoup to alter it?

Comment: @DavidRobinson not even close.  i'm very new to programming, so I wouldn't even know where to begin.  So, are you suggesting the info from yahoo will have changed?  Because I can see that info on Firebug.  I thought there was something wrong with the BeautifulSoup syntax.

Comment: No, that indicates something in the Yahoo output changed (an h2 tag missing). If no one's worked it out by the time I get to a computer I'll take a look!

Comment: Something is wrong with this Python code anyway- it should return the result variable after it sets the stock name (otherwise there's no point in printing it). This won't solve the error you're getting though

Comment: Looks like @samy.vilar nailed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Yahoo finance hasn't really changed their layout in a while, it seems they may have tweaked it slightly since the book was released, the info you need such as the `h2` info containing the stock symbol can be found within `yfi_rt_quote_summary` which is the container located on top of `yfi_quote_summary`

```
def find_quote_section(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)        
    quote = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'yfi_rt_quote_summary'})
    return quote
```

Also note that we need to return `result` if we want to print something either wise `None` is returned:

```
def parse_stock_html(html, ticker_name):
    quote = find_quote_section(html)
    result = {}
    tick = ticker_name.lower()
    result['stock_name'] = quote.find('h2').contents[0]
    return result

>>> print parse_stock_html(html, 'GOOG')
{'stock_name': u'Google Inc. (GOOG)'}
>>>
```

BTW note that `find` simply finds the first match.

```
>>> help(BeautifulSoup(html).find)
find(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, **kwargs) method of BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup instance
    Return only the first child of this Tag matching the given
    criteria.
```

which seems to be empty, `BeautifulSoup` also has `findall` which returns all matches.

```
>>> BeautifulSoup(html).findAll('h2')[3].contents[0]
u'Google Inc. (GOOG)'
```

it seems the fourth value is the one we are looking for ... Still, Im sure you are not doing this, but please don't parse the entire document every time, this can be quite expensive.